# Is it safe to use Array.sort() in synchronous way?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure whether the `Array.sort(callback)` is synchronous or asyncronous. But I have used the `Array.sort(callback)` to sort the date (`updateddate` which is stored in db as `string` type) in the following code snippet. Do i need to include `await` for `Array.sort(callback)` to ensure that the rest of the code is executed only when the array sorting is completed. Is it right way to use sorting above the synchronous code? Should I write the rest of the code inside the callback of `data.sort`?

```
modify_data(data,likesData){
    data.sort(function(a,b){
      return new Date(b.updateddate) - new Date(a.updateddate);
    })
    var nomination_group_id = _.groupBy(data,"submissionid")
    var likes_group
    var refined_arr = [];
    var likesData = likesData
    _.each(nomination_group_id,function(eachObj){
      var mapObj = new Map()
       mapObj.set('category',eachObj[0] ? eachObj[0].question : " ")
       mapObj.set('submitter',eachObj[0] ? eachObj[0].email : " ")
       refined_arr.push([ ...mapObj.values() ])
    })
    return refined_arr
}
```

Comment: Yes, `.sort` is most definitely synchronous. If someone wanted to use it asynchronously, they'd have to write a moderate amount of extra code (or more). It's like `forEach`, each call of the callback is executed synchronously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not sure whether the Array.sort(callback) is synchronous or asyncronous

1. Its safe, and its synchronous.
2. `Array.sort(sortFunction)` argument `sortFunction` is synchronously applied on each element of the array. Also, Javascript is single-threaded.

```js
const names = ['adelaine','ben', 'diana', 'carl']

const namesSortedAlphabetically = names.sort() // default is alphabetical sort
console.log('ALPHA SORT', namesSortedAlphabetically)

const namesSortedByLength = names.sort((a, b) => a.length > b.length) // custom sort
console.log('CUSTOM SORT', namesSortedByLength)
```

> Do i need to include await for Array.sort(callback)

Nope, since `Array.sort` is synchronous and doesn't return a `Promise`.

Comment: "Array.sort doesn't accept a callback, it accepts a sort function" - this statement is misleading because compare function is a callback. It's called back. It doesn't accept *asynchronous* callback.

Comment: @estus I get your point. Sorry my mind went back to node.js where 'callback' is, by convention, a function to be invoked after some async function completes. I've updated my answer for this.

Comment: No problem. Asynchronous callback is the first thing I think about when I hear about a callback, too, especially in Node.

Answer (score 3):

It's synchronous. Callback itself doesn't mean owner function is asynchronous.
Callback is just for deciding how to sort. So you can put your next logic outside of callback safely.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe & synchronous, because it is not a call back, it is just a comparator (compare function) [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

It is not calling this function at the end of doing something, it is using that function. Hope it calrifies

Comment: Compare function is a callback. That's the term for it.

Comment: If you see above mdn link, they didnt mentioned call back for a single time. but according to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming) you can call it as  synchronous callback. But I feel the term call back is little bit misleading here. It looks like duck but it didn't quack like duck

Comment: It's common programming term. A callback is a function that is passed to be called back later. When I hear about callbacks, async callback is the first thing I think about but that's an assumption. Btw, ESLint rule is called https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return

Answer (score 0):

`.sort()` is a function from the JavaScript language, and **it is determined to be synchronous** by the ECMAScript specification.

(Functions of the node.js framework are ususally asynchronous by default, but `.sort()` is coming from JavaScript language itself, not from the node.js framework.)

**It is very likely that you want to use it asynchronously**, when it comes to any production level application. You can:

- just wrap it around an asynchronous function scope, or
- write your own asynchronous implementation, or
- you can find several ready-to-use implementations for this issue, for example as an npm package.

**You are right, you need to pay attention that the code which is counting on the sorting to be done needs to be executed after sorting.** If you have chosen the first option in the 3 options before, you can:

- put stuff inside one and only callback (likely minor things), or
- build up a callback chain with `.then()`
- use the `await` keyword as you have mentioned.

Please note that I didn't want to confuse you with so many solutions, but it's necessary to be aware of them. They will become second nature over time. **If all of this feels a little confusing at this moment, I'd suggest you to start with the basic `.sort()` wrapped around an asynchronous function, and chained with `.then()` functions.**

---

#### EDIT

As my peer mentioned above, `.sort()` itself does not accept a callback function, but a sorting function instead. That is correct. In order to use `.sort()` asynchronously, you have to wrap it around your own asynchronous function, as I've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Modify input is a bad idea and you don't need `await` to make sure `data.sort` is synchronous, just declare a new variable to hold the result of sort like:

```
var sorted_data = data.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.updateddate) - new Date(a.updateddate);
})
var nomination_group_id = _.groupBy(sorted_data, "submissionid")
```